# Script started as `source` or `executable`?

Tags: shell-script, executable

Can we determine inside the very script whether it started as `source` (.) or `executable` (shebang or something alike)?

Comment: You should be able to `return` out of a dot script, but can't do so out of an executable script. That might not be very helpful.

Comment: That's exactly why I wanna know! :))

Comment: Does SHLVL get incremented differently in the two cases? I am away from a Unix shell at the moment, or I'd test it myself.

Comment: @JeffSchaller !! Maybe you just found the best answer. THEY DO! I never heard of this variable. Please do some tests to be sure thats ok, no side effects (works ok, all environments? Other shells? What other questions? Is it robust?), and write an answer here, and I'll change the accepted answer. This is very elegant.

Comment: Anyway, but how would you know if its supposed to be, lets say, `4`, instead of, say `3` or `5`?

Comment: @DrBeco: I'll have to expand on this another day, but I thought I'd get the breadcrumbs here for you to confirm/compare in your environment. I can find five differences in bash between a script called with source versus directly. (continued)

Comment: The five differences I found: SHLVL (which you point out is just an independent variable at that point); BASH_ARGV (which is the script name when sourced; versus empty when being called); BASH_ARGC (which is 1 when being sourced; versus undefined when being called); BASH_LINENO (tbd), and $0 (which is the parent's name when being sourced; the script's own name when being called).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test on `$0` if you have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
```

and make it executable (`chmod 755 test.sh`) and 
do:

```
source test.sh
```

you get `bash` (or something else depending on how you are logged in and what your shell is).

If you do

```
./test.sh
```

you get `./test.sh`, so assuming that the script knows how it is saved on the disc you should do:

```
if [ $(basename "$0") == "test.sh" ] 
then
   ..... your code here for non-sourced
else
   ..... your code here for sourced
fi
```

Comment: That depends heavily on the shell - and i think it might even depend on bash version. Definitiely zsh puts the file's - even a shell function's name - in $0 by default for sourced one. `ksh` does the same for sourced scripts. I thought i remembered bash doing it too - or it just does a separate $@? They're all different.

Comment: you are of course right about the different shells. Therefore testing on the script name might be the safer bet.

Comment: I think this might be a little hopeless. I didn't mean that in a snarky way, by the way. Though, looking back at it, i wish i had, that would have been a really good snark. What i meant was they all do it differently. `.` is just a shell's core functionality, really. A lot of shells, though, will put - at the very top of the script - `. $0` in the value of `$_`. So that's one way. Portably, though, i really believe it's hopeless.

Comment: In the specific case where the shell is `bash`:

The array variable **$BASH_SOURCE** will have one element at the top level of the script executed as a command, and more than one in a function or sourced file.