# Check how a script was started

Tags: bash

I'm making myself a few "helper" scripts, and the first one is to install NodeJS. The first issue I've just solved, was getting `source ~/.profile` to persist changes. I found out running `. /scripts/install-nodejs.sh` makes this work, but without the leading `.`, it doesn't.

Is there anyway I can tell in the script if it was called with the period before it, so if it isn't I can output myself a message remind me how to call the script properly?

For reference, this is the script so far

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Installing NVM..."
apt-get -qq install curl > /dev/null
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.16.1/install.sh | sh > /dev/null
echo "Done!"
source ~/.profile
```

Also, side question, is there a way to describe when a script is called with a preceding period?

Comment: I suggest against using `.` or `source` to run a script.  Doing so runs the script in the context of the current shell.  You don't know how that will affect the environment within the current shell -- it may have unintended consequences on future operations performed from that shell.

Comment: These scripts will be running a docker I'm using at home for a development. I understand the risks you say, but I'm my particular case, any thing that goes wrong, I can just reboot the docker container, and this would be one of the first commands run after boot.

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212943/117549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` is short hand for sourcing the script.  Sourcing a script is like calling each of the commands by hand.

Check this out [The Dot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114300/whats-the-meaning-of-a-dot-before-a-command-in-shell)